# yocto custom built linux iptables issue

Tags: iptables, yocto, hostapd

I am a beginner yocto user and I am working on a custom linux build for olinuxino a20-lime using yocto
I am trying to establish an access point using a rtl8192cu based dongle(TP-Link wn823n)
I followed this tutorial http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/Yocto/Wireless

When I ran `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` I got `No chain/target/match by that name` 
Now what do i do? change linux kernel build parameters or something?

My ap mode is working(I mean devices can connect) but internet connection seems to drop every now and then.
What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the kernel is not built with conntrack support (or modules are not loaded) thus not recognizing the "-m state".

Connection tracking can be allowed by setting the following kernel configuration items:

- CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK
- CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV4